# Is it logical to say "English is a balance"?

Tags: logic

[An American tutorial says](https://youtu.be/FStyKn4V8cE?t=114)

> English is a perfect balance between the long
>   versus short, the high versus low, the stressed versus the effortless ...

It seems to be a little bit illogical to say "English is a balance".

How about this one?

> ... there is a perfect balance in English ...

Comment: If I were to use your sentence, I would use "There is a perfect balance to English, between the...." honestly because it sounds more poetic and closer to the style of the rest of the sentence.  Not an answer because I can't say exactly why though...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thank you. I noticed one of your modification is about the use of preposition, does [the discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/245294/108867) fit here?

Comment: Your version may be more logical but the original is more striking. [Though I would prefer it with *the* short and *the* low.]

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you. The original is more striking because it is shorter, 5 words vs. 7 words?

Comment: @JJJohn It is braver. Good writing isn't always careful or logical. "We are such stuff as dreams are made on" is more vivid than the more logical "We are made from the same substance as dreams." "There is a perfect balance in English" is serviceable!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you. Is it a figure of speech?

Comment: @JJJohn I suppose it's a metaphor, yes.

Comment: For the 'to' comment, I guess it is because my mind supplies some missing words - "There is a perfect balance to (the structure of the) English (language).